# Default method for C# class

Tags: c#, class, syntax

Hi is it possible to specify a method that is the default method for a C# class?  I am writing a short class to output embed code for a video, here is the basic idea:

```
 public class EmbeddedVideo
{
    public string VideoPath { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public string EmbedCode()
    {
        return "...";
    }
}
```

Now if I were to say:

```
Response.Write(new EmbeddedVideo());
```

It would output the result of the GetType() method.  How can I specify that I would like the EmbedCode() method to be the default in this context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Override `ToString()`, which gets called in many scenarios where string conversion takes place:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return EmbedCode();
}
```

The "default" you're referring to is the default implementation of [`Object.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx), which simply happens to return the type name:

> The default implementation returns the fully qualified name of the type of the Object.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like by "default method" you mean "method which controls how instances of the type are displayed in methods like `Write`."  If so what you want to do is override the `ToString` method.

```
public override string ToString() {
  return EmbedCode();
}
```